# Field validation for month and day using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using a plugin that I found in http://www.mathachew.com/sandbox/jquery-autotab/
(please take a look at it to understand what I am talking about).

To change focus from an input after reaching the maxlength.. and also to validate the inputs
so I have this line here:

```
$("#day").autotab_filter({format:"custom", pattern:"0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-1]|3[01]"});
$("#month").autotab_filter({format:"custom", pattern:"0[1-9]|1[012]"});
```

It seems that my regex patterns are wrong or something! I've tried every possible combination. Please help!

This is an example http://jsfiddle.net/DAsRR/

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"?  What input did you give, what did you expect, what actually happened?

Comment: i want the input to accept only numbers between 01 and 31
this is an example http://jsfiddle.net/DAsRR/
take a look at the plugin page and you'll completly understand what it does ... the link has a very easy demo .. simple to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the answer guys .. if any one needs it in the future:
i must specify the opposit of numbers between 01 and 31 because this is the pattern that will be removed, not to be kept !
so to specify all numbers except the range from 01 to 31 this is the correct pattern :

```
[^0-9]|00|^[3][2-9]$|^[4-9]
```

explaination: `[^0-9]` will not except any character other than numbers ! from 0 to 9
00, is not a valid day number !
and `^[3][2-9]$` is for all numbers that start with with 3 and end with numbers from 2 to 9
35, is not a valid day number though !!
and `^[4-9]` is for numbers that start with 4 to 9 .
any other question about that pluging i'd be glad to answer it

Answer (score 2):

Your #day pattern:

```
0[1-9]|1[0-1]|2[0-1]|3[01]
```

Allows numbers from 01-09, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30 and 31.  I think you are looking for:

```
0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01]
```

Your #month pattern looks fine to me though.

Comment: please take a look at the plugin first

Comment: @user1283226 femtoRgon's solution works to select any day 01-31. [Here is a working example for you from regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=0%5B1-9%5D%7C1%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-9%5D%7C3%5B01%5D&input=22)

Comment: Your update to the question only incorporates half of the fix provided.  `2[0-1]` should be `2[0-9]`.